# merge pandas dataframe with itself to add new rows (like a cross join)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I would like to join my dataframe with itself in a way that it has the same amount of rows for a particular column. It sounds a bit complicated but I believe it is not when you see it. So here is an example:

| year | brand | series | model | version | value | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | bmw | A | 1X | plan | 3 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | B | 2X | plan | 8 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | A | 1X | sold | 1 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | C | 3X | sold | 10 | 1 |
| 2021 | bmw | A | 1X | sold | 50 | 20 |
| 2021 | bmw | C | 3X | sold | 50 | 20 |
| 2022 | bmw | A | 1X | prediction | 2 | 1 |
| 2022 | audi | D | 4X | prediction | 7 | 1 |

I would like to have the column `version` the same amount of `model` always, like this:

| year | brand | series | model | version | value | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | bmw | A | 1X | plan | 3 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | B | 2X | plan | 8 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | C | 3X | plan | Nan | Nan |
| 2022 | audi | D | 4X | plan | Nan | Nan |
| 2022 | bmw | A | 1X | sold | 1 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | C | 3X | sold | 10 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | A | 1X | sold | 1 | 1 |
| 2021 | bmw | C | 3X | sold | 50 | 20 |
| 2021 | bmw | A | 1X | sold | 50 | 20 |
| 2022 | audi | D | 4X | sold | Nan | Nan |
| 2022 | bmw | A | 1X | prediction | 2 | 1 |
| 2022 | audi | D | 4X | prediction | 7 | 1 |
| 2022 | bmw | B | 2X | prediction | Nan | Nan |
| 2022 | bmw | C | 3X | prediction | Nan | Nan |

As you can see, columns `year` to `version` are unique (I have more grouped unique columns). The rest are values(i.e. numeric data).

Answer (score 3):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to expose the missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.complete('version', 'model') 
   model     version  value
0     1X        plan    3.0
1     2X        plan    8.0
2     3X        plan    NaN
3     4X        plan    NaN
4     1X        sold    1.0
5     2X        sold    NaN
6     3X        sold   10.0
7     4X        sold    NaN
8     1X  prediction    2.0
9     2X  prediction    NaN
10    3X  prediction    NaN
11    4X  prediction    7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `pivot`, then `unstack`:

```
out = (df.pivot(index='model', columns='version', values='value')
         .unstack().reset_index(name='value')
         [df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
   model     version  value
0     1X        plan    3.0
1     2X        plan    8.0
2     3X        plan    NaN
3     4X        plan    NaN
4     1X  prediction    2.0
5     2X  prediction    NaN
6     3X  prediction    NaN
7     4X  prediction    7.0
8     1X        sold    1.0
9     2X        sold    NaN
10    3X        sold   10.0
11    4X        sold    NaN
```

A more cumbersome approach (IMO), using a MultiIndex:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['version'].unique(), df['model'].unique()],
                                 names=['version', 'model'])

out = (df.set_index(['version', 'model'])
         .reindex(idx).reset_index()[df.columns]
       )
```

Output:

```
   model     version  value
0     1X        plan    3.0
1     2X        plan    8.0
2     3X        plan    NaN
3     4X        plan    NaN
4     1X        sold    1.0
5     2X        sold    NaN
6     3X        sold   10.0
7     4X        sold    NaN
8     1X  prediction    2.0
9     2X  prediction    NaN
10    3X  prediction    NaN
11    4X  prediction    7.0
```

Comment: I get a `ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`.
that is because I also have other columns, such as `year', `month`. where should I add these columns? All of the columns are unique for the `value`.

Comment: How do you want to handle those? please update your example

Comment: I have updated the example. The second approach is not feasible as I have quite a few columns in real data.